# Random data loss in array c++

Tags: c++

Here's my problem.... In the code below, between the `char guess[4]` and `cin >> guess` my `answer`'s element at index 0 disappeared. Anyone knows why?

```
while(bullCount != 4)
{
    //Create the answer
    char answer[4];

    for(int loops = 0; loops < 4; loops++)
    {
        answer[loops] = createAnswerDigit(seed);
    }

    //Reset bullCount and cowCount from previous loop
    bullCount = 0;
    cowCount = 0;

    cout << "Enter your guess [1000-9999]: ";

    //Guess by player
    char guess[4];

    cout << "Answer[0]: " << answer[0] << "\n"; //Prints "Answer[0]: 4

    //Retrieve guess by player
    cin >> guess;

    cout << "Answer[0]: " << answer[0] << "\n" //Prints "Answer[0]: "

    for(int digitLoc = 3; digitLoc >= 0; digitLoc--)
    {
        //Do check backwards to prevent mistaking bulls for cows
        int check = checkGuess(guess[digitLoc], digitLoc, answer);

        if(check == cow)
        {
            cowCount++;
        }

        else if(check == bull)
        {
            bullCount++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what does createAnswerDigit do?

Comment: What is the input to `cin >> guess`?

Comment: @VerenaHaunschmid It returns a char representation of a random digit(atm it returns the same thing over and over for testing reasons).

Comment: @AndyG a 4 digit number (e.g. 4444, 3201)

Comment: `cin >> guess;` will result in undefined behaviour if the user enters 4 or more characters. There are probably countless SO questions and answers that explain why, but why bother? Just use `std::string` instead of built-in arrays.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`guess` has a size of `4`, however, you enter a number between `1000 - 9999` which is `4` characters long. Remember that in a string, there must be a `\0` at the end of the string, so `guess` is 1 character short. This might be overwriting the first element of `answer`. Try making `guess` of size 5, or better yet, use `std::string` instead.

Comment: I will try it, but I don't think it matters because it's not a c-string. It's a 4 digit number separated as 4 chars.

Comment: Edit: Nvm IT WORKS!! Thanks man! Been thinking about this for the last couple hours.... :D

Comment: oops sorry. I clicked it yesterday but it seems my internet lagged so it didn't. Accepted now!

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, the `guess` is an array of 4 chars. Whenever the user enters characters in range `1000-9999` it doesn't have a space for the string terminator '\0'. Thus, you need to define the array as:

```
char guess[5];
```

or you can use `string` implementations too